# Change two strings into one and separate them to create update query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I have these two strings in variables.

1. `$column = "name,body"`
2. `$data = "testname,testbody"`

I want to make UPDATE MySQL Query from it dynamically.

Query should output like this.

```
$query = "UPDATE `mytable` SET `name`='testname',`body`'testbody' WHERE id=1";
```

Or combine strings to variable

```
$generatedquery = "columnname='value',columnname='value'"

$query = "UPDATE `mytable` SET $generatedquery WHERE id=1";
```

Above two variables are dynamically coming, they can have multiple values.

Comment: look to `explode()` into two arrays, and then loop using `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for dynamic fields

```
$field = explode(',',$column);
$value = explode(',',$data);
$query = "UPDATE `mytable` SET ";
for($i=0;$i<count($field);$i++){
   $query .= $field[$i]." = '".$value[$i]."' ";
   if($i<count($field)-1){
     $query .= ", ";
   }
}
$query .= " WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: i

Comment: Done. Now Notice: Undefined offset: 2 :(

Comment: How can I remove last unnecessary comma?
UPDATE `test` SET name = 'test' , body = 'tetstnh' , = '' WHERE id=4

Comment: Use this corrected line for($i=0;$i<count($field);$i++)

Comment: Still have comma before "WHERE".

Comment: did you correct this `$i<=count($field)` in for loop? remove '=' in for loop condition part, this is correct `for($i=0;$i<count($field);$i++)`

Comment: Yes.
echo str_replace(",  WHERE", " WHERE", $query);
Solve my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

u can try thisway

```
 $column = "name,body";
$data = "testname,testbody";


$column_arr=explode(",",($column));
$data_arr=explode(",",($data));

foreach($column_arr as $ckey=>$cval){
  $where[]=$cval."='".$data_arr[$ckey]."'";
}

echo $query = "UPDATE `mytable` SET ".implode(",",$where)." WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: This will returns error because you miss ',' in every field

Comment: ohh..it's my mistake..now u can try

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it helps you

```
<?php

$column = "name,body"
$data = "testname,testbody"


$column_arr=explode(",",($column));
$data_arr=explode(",",($data));

foreach($column_arr as $ckey=>$cval){
  $where[]=$cval."=".$data_arr[$ckey];
}

$query = "UPDATE `mytable` SET implode(",",$where) WHERE id=1";
?>
```